# Can't see mesh objects using Atomic Blender (PDB/XYZ) importer

Tags: mesh, objects, add-on

[image: Image showing the difference between importing the file on Blender 3.3 vs 3.0.3]On blender 3.0.3 I can use the add on Atomic Blender (PDB/XYZ) to import an xyz file of a collection of atoms and transform them into a mesh of spheres. One mesh per each file imported. It works great but blender 3.0.3 on my distribution does not support GPU rendering.
Using blender 3.2 or 3.3 gives me a different behaviour. The mesh is imported but I only see the points in which the spheres should be, not the sphere themselves.
I'm new at using blender so I'd appreciate any help towards me being able to see the objects themselves.

Selecting the mesh and going to object and "Make instances real" create individual spheres. This is not a valid solution as I have thousands of atoms in my file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK. So turns out that the default when importing the xyz file has changed from Mesh to NURB. I don't know how that happened or what is the difference but that solves the behaviour.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the default in both 3.3.0 and 3.0 has been NURBs. Did you change the option to mesh in the importers option to make it work?